# Google Indexing Issue after htaccess changes

Tags: htaccess, google-index

I have a site called www.FuneralCoverFinder.co.za. I have about 30 pages on the site and usually have 29 indexed. (Excluding 15 blog posts) They are new.

I recently upgraded my entire site and made some redirection changes in my .htaccess file. I have made my url's more SEO friendly (Removing index.php/) and redirecting dead pages to working pages. I have tons of unique content all checked by grammarly and plagium to ensure I have no duplicate content.

I have since resubmited my sitemap to Google and now have only one page indexed. It was within a couple of minutes. I usually see results almost immediately after submitting, now it's stuck on 1 page indexed.

I assume I might have made errors in the .htaccess file as this was my first attempt. The site runs perfectly and all the url's redirect the way they should. I'm scared I have some or other loop, although the website runs fine.

I still see many of my old indexed pages in the SERP's, I'm just worried that the issue with the new sitemap can cause my rankings some harm. My website is pretty SEO optimized onsite. I have about 1500 indexed backlinks and have been building them steadily over about half a year.

I would really appreciate some clarity on this matter.

Comment: Google Webmastertools is your friend (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home)!

Comment: "1 page indexed" - that's likely to be from your newly submitted sitmap, but you have many pages indexed (albeit the old URLs) if you search for `site:example.com`. What is more worrying, however, is that every link from the homepage results in a 404?! Have you tried navigating your site?

Comment: That's not just links from the homepage, but it seems _every_ link on the site results in a 404? Yes, errors in your .htaccess file are a high probability!

Comment: Ok - links are working now. Did you change something?

Comment: You've also still got links going to the old /index.php/ ones in your content.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb about URLs is that you never change them unless you have no other option. So you made a mistake by removing index.php from your URLs.

However, the other rule of thumb is that if you *do* change URLs you install a search engine friendly 301 redirect from your old URL to your new one. So in that aspect you have done well.

Now as to why your old URLs still show up in the SERPS, that is to be expected. It takes time for Google to update its results pages to reflect changes in URLs. So the best thing you can do is to wait and see.